# getting count of received data over UDP socket (client-server chat app)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets, udp, client-server

I was trying to develop a client server app over `UDP network`. I have used listview to show the chat. But when user1 typed a very long sentence, the `listview` is showing the part of sentence (as its taking it in only one line).

So, I have written a logic to split the `sentdata` into lines if character count gets over 70. its works fine on server side but not working on the client side. I have set buffer array size to 2000.

When I tried print the received data `massage.length` on a label, its always showing it as 2000. (and that is why, the logic is not working). whats causing this? How to overcome it? I want the character count in received message .. (posting code with this)..

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sckt;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        byte[] buffer;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txtChat.Text = "";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //setting up the socket
            sckt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sckt.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            //getting users' IP
            txtLocalIp.Text = GetIPLocal();
        }

        private string GetIPLocal()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    return ip.ToString();

            return "127.0.0.1";
        }

        private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (buttonConnect.Text != "Disconnect !")
            {
                //binding socket to the Button
                epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtLocalPort.Text));
                sckt.Bind(epLocal);

                //connecting to Remote IP
                epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtRemoteIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtRemotePort.Text));
                sckt.Connect(epRemote);

                listView1.Columns.Add("",0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                listView1.Columns.Add("starting chat . . .", 444, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

                //listening to (receiving from) the specific port on Remote side
                buffer = new byte[2000];
                sckt.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
                buttonConnect.Text = "Disconnect !";
            }
            else
            {
                txtRemoteIp.Text = "";
                buttonConnect.Text = "Connect";
            }
        }

        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                if (buttonConnect.Text == "Disconnect !")
                {
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[2000];
                    receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

                    //converting byte[] to string
                    ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                    Console.Beep();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    int l = Convert.ToInt32(receivedData.Length) ;
                    label2.Text = "";
                     label1.Text = l.ToString();
                  string[] arr = new string[2];
                    ListViewItem itm;
                    arr[0] = "";

                    string firstString = receivedMessage;
                    if (firstString.Length > 70)
                    {
                        firstString = firstString.Remove(70);
                        string renewedString = receivedMessage;
                        renewedString = renewedString.Remove(0, 70);
                        if (renewedString.Length > 70)
                        {
                            string secondstring = renewedString.Remove(70);
                            renewedString = renewedString.Remove(0, 70);

                            if (renewedString.Length <= 70)
                            {
                                string s = "Friend : " + firstString;
                                arr[1] = s;
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                listView1.Items.Add(itm);

                                arr[1] = secondstring;
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                listView1.Items.Add(itm);

                                arr[1] = renewedString;
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                listView1.Items.Add(itm);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("message too long, reduce size !");
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr[1] = "Friend : " + firstString;
                        itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                        listView1.Items.Add(itm);


                    }
                    //callbacking again
                    buffer = new byte[2000];
                    sckt.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void buttonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (buttonConnect.Text == "Disconnect !")
                {
                    //convert string message to byte[]
                    ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[2000];
                    sendData = aEncoding.GetBytes(txtChat.Text);
                    //sending the Encoded message
                    sckt.Send(sendData);

                    string[] arr = new string[2];
                    ListViewItem itm;
                    arr[0] = "";

                    string firstString = txtChat.Text;
                    if (firstString.Length > 70)
                    {
                        firstString = firstString.Remove(70);
                        string renewedString = txtChat.Text;
                        renewedString = renewedString.Remove(0, 70);
                        if (renewedString.Length > 70)
                        {
                            string secondstring = renewedString.Remove(70);
                            renewedString = renewedString.Remove(0, 70);

                            if (renewedString.Length <= 70)
                            {
                                string s = "me : " + firstString;
                                arr[1] = s;
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                listView1.Items.Add(itm);

                                arr[1] = secondstring;
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                listView1.Items.Add(itm);

                                arr[1] = renewedString;
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                listView1.Items.Add(itm);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("message too long, reduce size !");
                            }


                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr[1] = "Me123 : " + firstString;
                        itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                        listView1.Items.Add(itm);
                    }

                    txtChat.Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Session Expired !");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read (and understand) the online help about `BeginReceiveFrom` and `EndReceiveFrom`, in your code the last parameter of `BeginReceiveFrom` is not correct.

When your callback function is called because there is data receive in the socket, you must extract the socket descriptor from the `IAsyncResult` parameter once you get the socket you need to call `EndReceiveFrom` to finish the operation correctly and returns the number of bytes read.

I think you need to understand how the `AysncFunction` works, nothing better than the online help of Visual Studio, there, you get everything you need to know in order to use these function BeginReceiveFrom/EndReceiveFrom/AsyncCallback, etc.

Comment: @ ja_mesa , your comment is very helpful . thnx ! :)
and i got my problem solved by changing one line to..

string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData).Trim('\x0');

thnx anyways..